# IAR Embedded Workbench: Why am I getting linker Error [Li005]?

Tags: linker, iar

I've added a new mycode.c and mycode.h file into my IAR Embedded Workbench project.  The files compile without error, but the linker fails with the message:

```
Error[Li005]: no definition for "myfun()" [referenced from C:\MyProj\Debug\Obj\main.o]
```

(Some names changed to protect the innocent.)

I checked the .map file, and `myfun()` does not appear there.  Any idea why `myfun()` is not getting linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any chance your project is a mixed C / C++ project?  If so, you need to include the following `extern "C" {  ... }` construct in your .h file (with the obvious name changes...):

```
// file: mycode.h
#ifndef MYCODE_H
#define MYCODE_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// your declarations go here...
void myfun();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // #ifndef MYCODE_H
```